# Phoneagap compiled apps black loading screen after splash

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

YO guys,

Im having a problem with my app.

I have Splash screen images and everyyhing, and they are being shown wonderful.  But... here it comes :)

After the Splash screen is done being shown, the screen blacks out, and it can take all from 2-10 secs before the real app shows.

Now this is very annoying, since this is not what is nice and smooth :)

Does anyone have a solution to this, know what im talking about, have an idea to this problem eg. and so forth ? :)

Best regards

Daniel

Comment: By chance are you loading a lot of remote JS/CSS files in the head tag of your HTML?

Comment: I just downloaded all the 3 files which where remote.  I still have the black screen.

Comment: Well if you are now referring to the files locally it should load faster but it depends on the size/complexity of your html.

Comment: There are around 150 lines HTML.  Jquery Mobile is included, there are about 150 lines of Phonegap stuff in javascript.  Nothing wild

Comment: Ofc JQM css is kinda big i guess hmm

Comment: Its just a lot of black screen loading.  The app it self is about 6MB in size.

Comment: I suggest putting in some console.log messages, or comment out some chunks of your code to try to find out where all the time is going

Comment: Yea problem is, that im not running eclipse or any kind of emulator where i can make some debug.  I rely on compiling my app through dreamweaver and then i just install it to my phone.  If you have any idea from what i just told you, please let me know im still here :)

Comment: I havent been able to find out whats going on.  I think my problem is that i have no debugger installed.  I gotta have to leave this for now as it is and go on with some other issues.  Thanks for all the answers. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a lot of testing myself.

I removed all external CSS and JS files and created then as Local instead.

I tryed re-writing my code.

I removed some not-used code.

I still do get the black screen after the splash-screen goes away.

Im going to accept my own answer, but not as a solution, but as a accept that this is hard to find a solution to.